# How to parse, persist and retrieve a string with tags separated by spaces?

Tags: grails, groovy, tags, tokenize

My database consists of 3 tables (one for storing all items, one for the tags, and one for the relation between the two):

Table: Post
Columns: PostID, Name, Desc

Table: Tag
Columns: TagID, Name

Table: PostTag
Columns: PostID, TagID

What is the best way to save a space separated string (e.g. "smart funny wonderful") into the 3 database tables shown above?

Ultimately I would also need to retrieve the tags and display it as a string again.    Thanks!

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more?  You can store strings with spaces in any String column.  Are you having problems parsing the data and inserting the data?

Comment: Hi melling.  I can tokenize the string into separate words but I'm not about the best way to proceed from there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Roughly, something like this:

```
class Post {
    static hasMany [tags:Tag]
}

class Tag {
    static belongsTo = Post
    static hasMany [posts:Post]
}

class someService {

    def createPostWithTags(name, desc, tags) {      
        def post = new Post(name: name, desc: desc).save()
        tags.split(' ').each { tagName ->
            def tag = Tag.findByName(tag) ?: new Tag(name: tagName)
            post.addToTags(tag).save()
        }       
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks Hates_.  This solution works well.  I just had to make a small change:
  def tag = Tag.findByName(tag) ?: new Tag(name: tagName).save()

Answer (score 1):

If you have a Tag Table, wouldn't you have a row for each Tag?

```
tag.id = 1; tag.name = 'smart'
tag.id = 2; tag.name = 'funny'
tag.id = 3; tag.name = 'wonderful'
```

In Groovy/Grails, you'd retrieve them as a list, possibly concatenating them into a space separated list for display.

Unless I'm really misunderstanding the question, Groovy/Grails/GORM will handle this with little or no code with the default scaffolding, no real coding required.

Comment: I agree, you're correct for retrieving and displaying the tags. I think he is stuck on how to take 3 words from 1 form field and insert 3 records in the tag table.

Comment: Yes, I think that's what I was trying to get at.  But I wasn't able to articulate the problem initially. I'll edit the original question now.

Comment: Looks like 'Hates_' has an answer